# Spring boot css is empty in browser

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hi I have a simple spring boot web app.

I'm trying to figure out why is my css showing up empty in the browser?

I'm quite sure it has something to do with configuration of resources but Spring changes so much that all of the older posts just confuse me...

Can somebody point me what do I need to do for my css to load correctly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{public/style.css}" href="../public/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{public/bootstrap.css}" href="../public/bootstrap.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">My Custom CMS Dashboard</h1>

        <a href="/addNewPost"><button class="btn btn-primary"> Add new Post </button></a>

    </body>
</html>
```

application.properties:

```
#h2
spring.h2.console.enabled = true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
#Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/cms_db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false


spring.resources.add-mappings=true
```

Comment: have you added any addResourceHandlers for static resource . Can you add that here

Comment: Hi no, and thanks for comment I'm a spring newbie so I didn't know I have to do this...

Comment: but where can I find non deprecated example of this lol

Comment: how does your application.properties (or yml) look like?

Comment: @PinkieSwirl I updated the question and included my application.properties

Comment: where is your public folder.. is it   src/main/resources/public/

Comment: yes it was... I managed to get bootstrap to work but only on html in static folder not on templates but my custom css is still loading empty in the browser...